# OpenCV replacing specific pixel values with another value in java

Tags: java, android, opencv, mat

i read about how to replace specific pixel values in Opebcv c++ is like the code below

```
Mat src;
// ... src is CV_32S

double oldVal = 0.0;
double newVal = Double.MIN_VALUE;

src.setTo(newVal, src == oldVal);
```

but after i read more i found out that logical operator on Mat don't work on java. so how can i do something similar to the code above because i need Mat that don't have zero to be divisor.

edit 1: cv::threshold wouldn't work becasue my mat is CV_32S, so the number could be negative numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to look into OpenCV [`compare`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare) API, to check for equality of each element of matrix with a scalar using `CMP_EQ` flag and which would yield you a binary mask that can be later used as second param in `src.setTo()`